# How to get the link of a file using Dropbox python API?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

So the Dropbox API is weird when "Downloading a file" with the Python version. It gives metadata about the file, but it doesn't actually download the file. Which is *weird* considering their API documentation says files_download(path) says it will download a file from a Dropbox when it just gets metadata.

```
k = dbx.files_get_temporary_link('/' + str(message))
```

This is a line of code that will bypass the files_download but where Metadata stops, more begins. When ran, it will throw out this class:

```
GetTemporaryLinkResult(metadata=FileMetadata(name='buiEKTw.png', id='id:8ZPbLGM5GIAAAAAAAAAACg', client_modified=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 1, 26, 27), server_modified=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 1, 26, 27), rev='e5047428b', size=905, path_lower='/buiektw.png', path_display='/buiEKTw.png', parent_shared_folder_id=None, media_info=None, sharing_info=None, property_groups=None, has_explicit_shared_members=None), link='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/AAAzE5ljMmZZ8jxjcKAh_uIym9Hy7tfC4Z67zvzMpakZDqhoje2BgXE9bTz1-dyy2QIuQJbJKiVfD1RvY4PI4AS1sPhTDRSgqpXMU7XBasZ_gw5lNEpyGiYM-m5lQDozXf6oP7WAJjb1NqwRlQuPfRHpsJq7PRn4alBddVdzb6MZTyBdlvzd55hcxqhbU3d9o84mOR9qGh3zl6rSzYUWbhr7RoQVscpq2qug-lnTelc9eQ')
```

I just want the link at the end of the class/metadata and I can't seem to get it. The link itself is 280 characters and with the quotes is 282. And the metadata is subject to change everytime it gets the metadata.

Comment: Have you tried `k.link` or `k.link()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`files_get_temporary_link`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_get_temporary_link) method returns a [`GetTemporaryLinkResult`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.files.GetTemporaryLinkResult). As sal commented, you can use `.link` to access the `link` from that object, like this:

```
result = dbx.files_get_temporary_link(filePath)

print(result.link)
```

Note that that method returns a link to the file. If you want to access the file content directly, you can use [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download) as shown below:

This uses the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to download a file from the Dropbox API at the remote path `/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt` to the local file `Prime_Numbers.txt`:

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("<ACCESS_TOKEN>")

with open("Prime_Numbers.txt", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt")
    f.write(res.content)
```

`<ACCESS_TOKEN>` should be replaced with your access token.